# Porting an Visual Studio Code extension from Windows to MacOS

Tags: node.js, macos, visual-studio-code, cross-platform

I am developing an extension for VsCode for Windows. Next, I want to make it portable for Linux and Mac OS. On Linux, all basic functions started without problems. When launched on MacOS, there is a duplication of items in the context menu. **At the same time on Windows and Linux everything works fine.**
Is there any information about creating a portable extension for VsCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything turned out to be very simple and has nothing to do with porting to MacOS. During development, I changed the value of the `name` field in the package.json file. Because of what, when installing a new version, I added another version of my extension. Duplicate registration of commands of both extensions and led to such strange behavior. Keep this in mind.